# Fetch boolean value from database

Tags: c#, database, boolean

```
protected void ImageButton5_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ENTERKEY001;Initial Catalog=ContactManagement;Integrated Security=True");//DataBase Connection
    String NAME = TextBox4.Text;
    SqlCommand getID = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID FROM UserDetailsOne WHERE NAME='" + NAME + "'", con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr = getID.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.Read())
    {
        String ID = dr[0].ToString();
        SqlCommand getBLOCK = new SqlCommand("SELECT BLOCK FROM UserDetailsTwo WHERE ID='" + ID + "'", con);
        dr.Close();
        SqlDataReader dr0 = getBLOCK.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr0.Read())
        {
            String BLOCK = dr0[0].ToString();
            if (BLOCK == "false")
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select NAME,UserDetailsOne.ID,ADDRESS,GENDER,MOBILENO,PHOTO from UserDetailsOne left join UserDetailsTwo on UserDetailsOne.ID=UserDetailsTwo.ID where NAME like @NAME", con);
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
                con.Close();

            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("1.aspx");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you getting your database values ? Where is your code ? What is the datatype of the value in database ?

Comment: `UserDetailsTwo.Rows[]` which rows column value you want to test or is it always contain single row ?

Comment: The NAME will be typed in the text box and the button will be clicked, that NAME is in table 'UserDetailsOne' this NAME reffers the 'ID' and then to the 'ID' of the 'UserDetailsTwo'. Row[ ] means the ID of that particular NAME which is typed in the text box.

Comment: `Row[]` is array of multiple rows so which rows values you want to access ? You need index of that rows. In short how you are going to decide `UserDetailsTwo` which row you want to access.

Comment: ok then index of row is Rows[2]

Comment: Second point is why you are executing the same query on getting the database into reader and adapter you can do that in single place or are you executing the separate query for each reader line. Please post what you are trying to do in question.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Convert.ToBoolean(tablename.Rows[index row][index columns])=true)
{
  //do sth
}
```

one way to access to table is index of columns or if you want to find with columns name you can write name "" in []